# Build multiple images from multiple dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to build the multiple images by managing two different dockerfiles?
In my case I want to keep two dockerfile suppose Dockerfile_app1 Dockerfile_app2 within the build context.

```
docker build -t <image_name> .
```

The above will pick the dockerfile named as `Dockerfile`

```
docker build -t <image_name> Dockerfile_app1
```

This is also not working for my case as It's expecting the file name as `Dockerfile.`

I have tried by docker-compose build also. However it din't work.

```
app1:
  build: Dockerfile_app1
  ports:
   - "80:80"
app2:
  build: Dockerfile_app2
  ports:
   - "80:80"
```

Comment: The `build` directive in your `docker-compose.yml` expects a directory, not a filename.  The `docker build` command does allow you to specify a name other than `Dockerfile`; check the man page or help output (and make sure you're running a recent Docker release).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use the `-f` argument to `docker build` to specify the name of the Dockerfile to use:

```
$ docker build -t <image_name> -f Dockerfile_app1 .
...
```

Or in Compose you can use the `dockerfile` key from version 1.3 onwards:

```
app1:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile_app1
  ports:
   - "80:80"
app2:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile_app2
  ports:
   - "80:80"
```

Note that the `build` key is for the build context, not the name of the Dockerfile (so it looked for a directory called `Dockerfile_app1` in your case).

Comment: Thanks Adrian, it working if i'm using docker build -t <image_name> -f Dockerfile_app1 option. However i'm getting "Unsupported config option for app2 service: 'dockerfile'" message if i'm trying to build it by using docker-compose build. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of Compose are you using? You probably just need to upgrade. `dockerfile` should be correct: https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/

Comment: I had 1.2.0 which was not working, after updating to 1.3.1 it's working fine for me,Thanks :)

Comment: `dockerfile` is supposed to be (along with `args` and `context`) a property inside `build`, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/dockerfile . Could you update the indentation in your answer please?

Comment: @peetasan depends if you're using the new or old Compose syntax :(